# Why can't I end a raw string with a backslash?

Tags: python, string, rawstring

I am confused here, even though raw strings convert every `\` to `\\` but when this `\` appears in the end it raises error.

```
>>> r'so\m\e \te\xt'
'so\\m\\e \\te\\xt'

>>> r'so\m\e \te\xt\'
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

**Update:**

This is now covered in [Python FAQs](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html) as well: [Why can’t raw strings (r-strings) end with a backslash?](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You still need `\` to escape `'` or `"` in raw strings, since otherwise the python interpreter doesn't know where the string stops. In your example, you're escaping the closing `'`.

Otherwise:

```
r'it wouldn\'t be possible to store this string'
r'since it'd produce a syntax error without the escape'
```

Look at the syntax highlighting to see what I mean.

Comment: but the \ inside the string then should also escape the character next to them, instead they simply convert to \\.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: No, in a raw string, a `\` _only_ escapes a quote character.

Comment: yes, SO is not allowing me to write a single \ in code formatting.;)
Thanks I got the point.

Comment: still it's not a single '\' SO converts it to '\\'.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean...

Comment: A backslash in a raw string doesn't escape anything. You cannot produce the string `'''"""` with a raw string literal. Try it.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. r'\'' Produces "\\'" in Python 3, so ` doesn't actually escape the `'`. The documentation is unclear in this case, there is no escaping going on, it's just the string literal parsing that gives an error.

Comment: @Lennart, @Karl: I stand corrected. That behavior is very odd then. I can produce that string with `r"'''"'"""'`, but that's kinda cheating.

Comment: Yeah, it's two literals, and only one of them is raw. :-)

Answer (score 9):

Raw strings can't end in single backslashes because of how the parser works (there is no actual escaping going on, though). The workaround is to add the backslash as a non-raw string literal afterwards:

```
>>> print(r'foo\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(r'foo\')
                 ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print(r'foo''\\')
foo\
```

Not pretty, but it works. You can add plus to make it clearer what is happening, but it's not necessary:

```
>>> print(r'foo' + '\\')
foo\
```

Answer (score 5):

Python strings are processed in two steps:

1. First the tokenizer looks for the closing quote. It recognizes backslashes when it does this, but doesn't interpret them - it just looks for a sequence of string elements followed by the closing quote mark, where "string elements" are either (a character that's not a backslash, closing quote or a newline - except newlines are allowed in triple-quotes), or (a backslash, followed by any single character).
2. Then the contents of the string are interpreted (backslash escapes are processed) depending on what kind of string it is. The `r` flag before a string literal only affects this step.

Comment: It seems the Python scanner stores the 'r' as a token, then goes on to scan the string using the *default* string processing rules, instead of rules where a baskslash is treated as an ordinary character. This issue is discussed at http://stackoverflow.com/q/30283082/3259619.

Answer (score 3):

Quote from https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals:

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the
>   backslash remains in the result; for example, **r"\"" is a valid string
>   literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote;**
>   r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an
>   odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in
>   a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following
>   quote character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a
>   newline is interpreted as those two characters as part of the literal,
>   not as a line continuation.

So in raw string, backslash are not treated specially, ***except*** when preceding `"` or `'`. Therefore, `r'\'` or `r"\"` is not a valid string cause right quote is escaped thus making the string literal invalid. In such case, there's no difference whether `r` exists, i.e. `r'\'` is equivalent to `'\'` and `r"\"` is equivalent to `"\"`.