# Shouldn't r'\' be a valid string value in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why can’t I end a raw string with a \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168076/why-cant-i-end-a-raw-string-with-a)

Given `r'\\'` is equivalent to `'\\\\'`, why `r'\'` isn't equivalent to `'\\'`?

What I got on my python3.2 was

```
print(r'\')
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print(r'\')
              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: I also had the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168076/why-cant-i-end-a-raw-string-with-a

Answer (score 11):

You cannot have a backslash as the last character in a raw string unless it is part of an even number of backslashes; it escapes the closing quote.

Compare this to:

```
>>> r'\ '
'\\ '
```

From the [string literal documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> When an `'r'` or `'R'` prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal `r"\n"` consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase `'n'`. String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the string; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).

Comment: Oh, I see, otherwise there is no way to include `'` in a raw string. Thx.

Comment: @updogliu: basically, you can only include *just* a `'` character (no backslash proceding it) by using double quotes (`r""`) or a tripple-quoted raw literal (`r'''string'''` or `r"""string"""`).