# error with string with ending backslash

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why can’t I end a raw string with a \](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168076/why-cant-i-end-a-raw-string-with-a)

Why is this syntax correct:

```
baseFilePath = r"C:\SVN\google code"
```

while this gives the error

```
baseFilePath = r"C:\SVN\google code\"
```

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 2):

Fromt the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a
>   backslash is included in the string without change, and all
>   backslashes are left in the string. For example, the string literal
>   r"\n" consists of two characters: a backslash and a lowercase 'n'.
>   String quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash
>   remains in the string; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal
>   consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is
>   not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd
>   number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a
>   single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote
>   character). Note also that a single backslash followed by a newline is
>   interpreted as those two characters as part of the string, not as a
>   line continuation.

**Specifically, a raw string cannot end in a
single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote
character)**

Comment: As far as I understand this there is no possibility to add a backslash at the end of a 'r' string ?. It is either interpreted as a escape sequence or with double slashes added twice.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you are escaping the quote `\"` is the escape sequence for a `"`

To use the backslash, you should use a double backslash `\\`

This should work :

```
baseFilePath = "C:\\SVN\\google code\\"

>>> print(baseFilePath)
    C:\SVN\google code\
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join`, it avoids this and takes care of using the OS-appropriate directory separators:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('C:','svn','google code')
'C:/svn/google code'
```

Comment: nice function, but I would only use it to join variables holding paths. Here I have many manually inserted paths that change frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the backslash escapes the ending `"`.
If you want to use `\` in a string, the most safe way is to escape the backslash itself.

Try this:

```
baseFilePath = "C:\\SVN\\google code\\"
```

I'd recommend it instead of using a raw string. The characters which need an escape are described in the [python doc](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html).

Comment: `r"C:\\SVN\\google code\\"` is equal to `"C:\\\\SVN\\\\google code\\\\"`

Comment: I use the r" syntax because I want to avoid the double slashes under all circumstances.