# Replacing characters within a list

Tags: python, replace

I have to replace certain characters in each tuple in a list.I know how to do it with just a basic string.

```
import string
s = 'This:is:awesome'
ss = s.replace(':', '/')
print ss
```

However, how would I go about looping through a list?

```
import string
finalPathList = []
pathList = ['List of 10+ file path names']
for lines in pathList:
    ss = pathList.replace('\', '/')
    print ss
    finalPathList.append(ss)
```

All I need to do is go through each tuple of filenames, and replace all of the `"\"` 's with `"/"` 's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: apply `replace` to `lines`, not `pathList`.

Comment: Does he really need to `import string` for this ?

Comment: As a side not you can't use `"\"`, use `"\\"` or better use raw strings. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168076/why-cant-i-end-a-raw-string-with-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
>>> pathList = [r"C:\Users", r"C:\Documents", r"C:\Downloads\Test"]
>>> finalPathList = []
>>> for element in pathList:
          finalPathList.append(element.replace("\\", "/"))


>>> finalPathList
['C:/Users', 'C:/Documents', 'C:/Downloads/Test']
```

Or by using List Comprehension.

```
>>> finalPathList = [elem.replace("\\", "/") for elem in pathList]
>>> finalPathList
['C:/Users', 'C:/Documents', 'C:/Downloads/Test']
```

Comment: +1 Use raw strings, else something like `"C:\test"` will result in unwanted results.

Answer (score 2):

```
finalPathList = map(lambda x: x.replace('\\', '/'), pathList)
```

`map` is a nice way to apply a function to each `list` item.

Answer (score 1):

Correcting your code...

```
finalPathList = []
pathList = ['List of 10+ file path names']
for lines in pathList:
    ss = lines.replace('\\', '/')
    print ss
    finalPathList.append(ss)
```